# How to create table in SQL Dev Web with all possible DATATYPES and insert values in it?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table which consists all possible datatypes w.r.t Oracle Database through SQL Dev Web.

Table is getting created but, while inserting values I get this error:

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here
> Error at Line: 7 Column: 0

Here is my SQL command to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE DataTypes 
(
    db_INTEGER INTEGER,
    db_NUMBER NUMBER(4,0),
    db_RAW RAW(200),
    db_DATE DATE,
    db_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
    db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE,
    db_CHAR CHAR(400),
    db_ROWID ROWID,
    db_UROWID UROWID,
    db_FLOAT FLOAT(10),
    db_NCHAR NCHAR(400),
    db_NVARCHAR2 NVARCHAR2(400),
    db_VARCHAR2 VARCHAR2(400),
    db_BINARY_FLOAT BINARY_FLOAT,
    db_BINARY_DOUBLE BINARY_DOUBLE,
    db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
    db_INTERVAL_YEAR_TO_MONTH INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH,
    db_INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
    db_LONG LONG,
    db_BLOB BLOB,
    db_CLOB CLOB,
    db_BFILE BFILE,
    db_BOOLEAN CHAR(1),

    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (db_INTEGER)
);
```

Here is my insert table command:

```
INSERT INTO DataTypes (
db_INTEGER,
db_NUMBER,
db_RAW,
db_DATE,
db_TIMESTAMP,
db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE,
db_CHAR,
db_ROWID,
db_UROWID,
db_FLOAT,
db_NCHAR,
db_NVARCHAR2,
db_VARCHAR2,
db_BINARY_FLOAT,
db_BINARY_DOUBLE,
db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE,
db_INTERVAL_YEAR_TO_MONTH,
db_INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND,
db_LONG,
db_BLOB,
db_CLOB,
db_BFILE,
db_BOOLEAN
) VALUES (
1,
1234,
'48656C6C6F',
TO_DATE('17-DEC-80','DD-MON-RR'),
TO_TIMESTAMP('1995-06-02T04:29:11.002Z'),
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1995-06-02T04:29:11.002Z'),
'Hello World! ',
'AAAGq9AAEAAAA0bAAA',
'AAAGq9AAEAAAA0bAAA',
123.45,
'Hello World! ',
'Hello World! ',
'Hello World! ',
123.456,
123.456789,
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('1995-06-02T04:29:11.002Z'),
"P-123Y3M",
"P-5DT3H55M",
'123qwerty456',
'bGVhc3VyZS4=',
'Hello World! ',
BFILENAME('C:\Download', 'sample.txt'),
'Y'
);
```

Please help me with proper commands to create table with all DataTypes and insert records into it.

So I can perform CRUD operations on it.

Comment: `"P-123Y3M", "P-5DT3H55M",` should be `INTERVAL '-123-3' YEAR(4) TO MONTH,
INTERVAL '-5 3:55' DAY(2) TO MINUTE,`. Double quotes are for column/table identifiers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the precision on the interval to be large enough to store your data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DataTypes (
db_INTEGER INTEGER,
db_NUMBER NUMBER(4,0),
db_RAW RAW(200),
db_DATE DATE,
db_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP,
db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE,
db_CHAR CHAR(400),
db_ROWID ROWID,
db_UROWID UROWID,
db_FLOAT FLOAT(10),
db_NCHAR NCHAR(400),
db_NVARCHAR2 NVARCHAR2(400),
db_VARCHAR2 VARCHAR2(400),
db_BINARY_FLOAT BINARY_FLOAT,
db_BINARY_DOUBLE BINARY_DOUBLE,
db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
db_INTERVAL_YEAR_TO_MONTH INTERVAL YEAR(3) TO MONTH,
db_INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
db_LONG LONG,
db_BLOB BLOB,
db_CLOB CLOB,
db_BFILE BFILE,
db_BOOLEAN CHAR(1),
CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (db_INTEGER)
);
```

Then use literal data types and convert strings to the appropriate types:

```sql
INSERT INTO DataTypes (
db_INTEGER,
db_NUMBER,
db_RAW,
db_DATE,
db_TIMESTAMP,
db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_LOCAL_TIME_ZONE,
db_CHAR,
db_ROWID,
db_UROWID,
db_FLOAT,
db_NCHAR,
db_NVARCHAR2,
db_VARCHAR2,
db_BINARY_FLOAT,
db_BINARY_DOUBLE,
db_TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIME_ZONE,
db_INTERVAL_YEAR_TO_MONTH,
db_INTERVAL_DAY_TO_SECOND,
db_LONG,
db_BLOB,
db_CLOB,
db_BFILE,
db_BOOLEAN
) VALUES (
1,
1234,
'48656C6C6F',
DATE '1980-12-17',
TIMESTAMP '1995-06-02 04:29:11.002',
TIMESTAMP '1995-06-02 04:29:11.002 UTC',
'Hello World! ',
'AAAGq9AAEAAAA0bAAA',
'AAAGq9AAEAAAA0bAAA',
123.45,
N'Hello World! ',
N'Hello World! ',
'Hello World! ',
123.456,
123.456789,
TIMESTAMP '1995-06-02 04:29:11.002 UTC',
INTERVAL '-123-3' YEAR(3) TO MONTH,
INTERVAL '-5 3:55' DAY TO MINUTE,
'123qwerty456',
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('bGVhc3VyZS4='),
'Hello World! ',
BFILENAME('C:\Download', 'sample.txt'),
'Y'
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ohGeqOgy)